# как записать xml в таблицу с типом xml

Tags: c#

есть код

```
connection.Open();
                    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
                    command.Connection = connection;
                    command.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO innXml (inn,xml) VALUES (@inn, @xml)";
                    command.Parameters.Add("@inn", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
                    command.Parameters.Add("@xml", SqlDbType.Xml);
                    this.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;
```

inn c типом VarChar все нормально записывается в базу. А вот как быть с файлом xml не понимаю. Желательно привести пример кода т.к. я только разбираюсь в c#=)))

Comment: у ячейки есть тип xml. возможно ли положить туда целиком xml файл чтобы потом скачать?

Comment: вы передаете значение в параметр? command.Parameters.Add("@xml", SqlDbType.Xml).Value = myXml; какая ошибка выходт?

Comment: нет ошибки. просто пустая ячейка в базе(

Comment: я понимаю что можно сделать байтовый массив и его просто запихнуть в ячейку. но хотелось бы сам xml файл.

Answer (score 1):

XML - это самый обычный текст, но написанный по особым правилам, которые не мешают ему оставаться текстом. XML-файл это обычный текстовый файл с расширением .xml, которое нужно исключительно пользователю и иногда ОС для открытия файла в удобной пользователю программе.

Тип `xml` в SQL, отличается от других текстовых типов только дополнительной функциональностью, которая может быть применена к ячейкам такого типа (не поддерживается LIKE, поддерживается XPath и т.д.). С точки зрения хранения данных - это обычный текстовый тип. Поэтому можете спокойно передавать в параметры строку, которая представляет валидный XML. Как вы ее получите не имеет значения, прочитаете из файла или примените что-то вроде `XElement.Tostring()`.